# tonymillion Reachability doesn't work until a connection change

Tags: ios, reachability

This is my code:

```
    self.reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    self.reachability.reachableBlock = {
        (let reach: Reachability!) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print(true)
        }
    }
    self.reachability.unreachableBlock = {
        (let reach: Reachability!) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print(false)
        }
    }
    self.reachability.startNotifier()
```

I called this in `viewDidAppear`, but nothing happened. However, when I turned iPhone to flight mode, `false` was printed immediately. And when I switched off flight mode, `true` was also printed.

What I need is to check the network availability instead of change. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blocks are run when the reachability status changes, if you need to check the current reachability status and not wait for a change then you can do:

```
if self.reachability.isReachable() {
    // reachable
} else {
    // not reachable
}
```